# Unknown LDAP cn=config admin password

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, password

When I installed OpenLDAP I was asked to create a password for an admin user but now I realize there's another admin user for `cn=config` whose password I don't know. Does anyone know how should I proceed to change or get that admin password? I'm on a fresh Ubuntu 13.10 install.

I need that password cause I'm trying to setup sudo-ldap.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know how the current Ubuntu packages do the initial OpenLDAP setup but both in 10.04 and 12.04 that process didn't account very well for cn=config. If set you should find the password in the attribute `olcRootPW` in `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif` (it's probably base64 encoded).

To change the password use `ldapmodify` as root. Save this as an LDIF file `rootpw_cnconfig.ldif`:

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: foobar123
```

**Note:** In order to change the root password on CentOS7 use `dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config` instead of `dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config`.

Obviously set your password to something other than `foobar123`. Then run `ldapmodify`:

```
$ sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f rootpw_cnconfig.ldif
```

This presumes that the LDAP server and the `cn=config` database can be accessed using the ldapi protocol (`-H ldapi:///`) and that external SASL authentication (`-Y EXTERNAL`) is enabled and working, which it should by default on new OpenLDAP setups in Debian and Ubuntu. If you look at `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif` it should contain an  attribute `olcAccess`:

```
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
  ,cn=auth manage by * break
```

Comment: Running on CentOS I get an `ldap_modify: Object class violation (65)`with `additional info: attribute 'olcTLSCertificateFile' not allowed`. Do you have any idea how to resolve that issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know how to change access rights for `cn=config` which has `access to * by * none` by default (in some openldap distributes) here is workaround:

1. create appropriate slapd.conf which contains:

```
database config
rootdn "cn=admin,cn=config"
rootpw password
access to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth manage by * break
```

2. convert it into LDIF:

```
slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/
```

3. run `slapd`
4. add/modify LDAP databases using SASL authorization, for example:

```
sudo ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -Q -H ldapi:/// <<EOF
dn: cn=config
objectClass: olcGlobal
cn: config
olcIdleTimeout: 30
olcLogLevel: stats config sync
olcArgsFile: /run/openldap/slapd.args
olcPidFile: /run/openldap/slapd.pid

dn: cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: schema

include: file:///etc/openldap/schema/core.ldif

dn: olcDatabase=frontend,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcFrontendConfig
olcDatabase: frontend

dn: olcDatabase=mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: mdb
olcSuffix: dc=my-domain,dc=com
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com
olcRootPW: secret
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/openldap/openldap-data
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
EOF
```